# SWF becomes very small when Embedding 2 SWFs side by side using float

Tags: html, css, css-float, flash

When I use float to put 2 SWFs side by side, my first SWF oddly becomes very small.

For some reason, when setting its width to 100%, it's width becomes around 300px, instead of taking up the width that's not taken by the other SWF, which is around 900px.

I need to set it as 100% so that its width auto-adjusts to the width of the browser window, instead of being a still 900px. Is there something I'm doing wrong? This is my embed code...

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#container {
   overflow:hidden;
   position: absolute;
    right: 100px;
}
#em-box {
float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
#em-box2 {
   float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
</style></head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFCC">
<div id="container">
<div id="em-box"><embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="game.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></div>
<div id="em-box2"><embed width="200" height="600" name="plugin" src="chat.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></div>
</div>


</body></html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use an iframe instead of embed?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the float only on the fixed element and adjust the margins of the other to encompass it's width plus spacing. Also, set the container width if you want to get the entire page.

http://jsfiddle.net/8kmnyr54/

```
#container { /* defined width (optional) */
    overflow:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 100px;
    width: 80%;
}

#em-box { /* defined fixed width */
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 400px
}

#em-box2 { /* removed float and changed margin */
    margin: 10px;
    margin-left: 420px; /* em-box width + margins + padding + desired extra space */
}
```